# Python: Appending an element to an element of a list of lists

Tags: python, list, append

Could somebody please explain the following behaviour?

```
X=2*[[]]
print X
X[0].append(1)
print X
```

yields

```
[[], []]
[[1], [1]]
```

I would expect the last list to be `[[1], []]`. Indeed, the following

```
X=[[],[]]
print X
X[0].append(1)
print X
```

yields

```
[[], []]
[[1], []]
```

Why this difference?

Comment: Thanks! I should have done '[[] for n in range(2)]'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multiplication syntax you used creates a shallow copy of the contents. Each list element within will be a new reference to the same list.

The second example you give actually produces a list of two different lists.

```
y = 2*[x]
```

is roughly equivalent to doing

```
y = [x] + [x]
```

The `x` in both places refers to the same list.

```
>>> y = 2*[[]]
>>> y[0].append(1)
>>> y
[[1], [1]]
>>> x = []
>>> y = [x] + [x]
>>> y
[[], []]
>>> y[0].append(1)
>>> y
[[1], [1]]
```

To create a list that functions as your second example, try

```
>>> y=[[] for n in range(2)]
>>> y[0].append(1)
>>> y
[[1], []]
```